# Powershell only returns 2 values, using "return x,y"

Tags: powershell

I have a weird problem. I have a function that is supposed to return 1 or 2 values, a letter and a number. 
For some reason, it only works when I specify the return as

```
return $x, $y
```

but it doesn't work like this:

```
return $x
return $y
```

The code:

```
$ModelsDesktop = @("Dimension","Optiplex")
$ModelsLaptop = @("Latitude","Venue")

<#
Returns L or D depending on the Computer Name. Sets U if the model is uncertain.
#>
Function Get-TypeByComputerName{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$ComputerName
    )

    Process {
        if ($ComputerName -like "*-L-*" -or $ComputerName -like "*-LT-*") {
            $ModelType = "L"
        }

        elseif ($ComputerName -like "*-D-*" -or $ComputerName -like "*-WRK-*") {
            $ModelType = "D"
        }

        else {
            $ModelType = "U" #unsure
        }

        return $ModelType
    }

}


<#
Returns L or D depending on the Computer Model. Sets U if the model is uncertain.
#>
Function Get-TypeByModel{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, Position = 0)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Model
    )

    Process {
        if (($ModelsLaptop | %{($Model) -like("*$_*")}) -contains $true) {
            $ModelType = "L"
        }

        elseif (($ModelsDesktop | %{($Model) -like("*$_*")}) -contains $true) {
            $ModelType = "D"
        }

        else {
            $ModelType = "U"
        }

        return $ModelType
    }

}


<#
Returns L or D depending on the Computer Name and Model. Sets a flag if the model is uncertain.
#>
Function Get-Type{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$ComputerName,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [string]$Model
    )

    Process {
        if ((($ComputerName | Get-TypeByComputerName) -eq ($Model | Get-TypeByModel)) -and (($ComputerName | Get-TypeByComputerName) -ne "U")) {
            $ModelType = ($ComputerName | Get-TypeByComputerName)
        }

        elseif (($ComputerName | Get-TypeByComputerName) -ne "U") {
            $ModelType = ($ComputerName | Get-TypeByComputerName)
            $Flag = 1
        }

        elseif (($Model | Get-TypeByModel) -ne "U") {
            $ModelType = ($Model | Get-TypeByModel)
            $Flag = 1
        }

        else {
            $ModelType = "D"
            $Flag = 1
        }

        return $ModelType
        return $Flag
    }

}
```

The value:

```
$test = New-Object psobject -Property @{ComputerName="crd-l-02-00001";Model="opti 343"}
```

Output with 2 return statements (as in the previous code):

```
$test

ComputerName   Model   
------------   -----   
crd-l-02-00001 opti 343



PS C:\Users\u0096902> (Get-Type -ComputerName $test.ComputerName -Model $test.Model)
L
```

Output with the corrected "return $ModelType, $Flag":

```
$test

ComputerName   Model   
------------   -----   
crd-l-02-00001 opti 343



PS C:\Users\u0096902> (Get-Type -ComputerName $test.ComputerName -Model $test.Model)
L
1
```

What am I missing? Can't seem to figure it out. It only seems to return the first "return", but I don't know why.

This example code seems to work perfectly fine:

```
function get-multiplereturnvalues {
  "Return value 1"
  "Return value 2"
}

$return = get-multiplereturnvalues
$return[0]  # Outputs "Return value 1"
$return[1]  # Outputs "Return value 2"
```

Comment: "In computer programming, a return statement causes execution to leave the current subroutine and resume at the point in the code immediately after where the subroutine was called, known as its return address."

Comment: Seems that I missed the quotes around the example code. D'oh! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"In computer programming, a return statement causes execution to leave the current subroutine and resume at the point in the code immediately after where the subroutine was called, known as its return address."

Once you call return you are saying that you are finished with that function.

Answer (score 3):

From `Get-Help about_Return`:

LONG DESCRIPTION
    The Return keyword exits a function, script, or script block. It can be 
    used to exit a scope at a specific point, to return a value, or to indicate 
    that the end of the scope has been reached.

Your first `Return` is forcing immediate exit from the function, so the second one never gets a chance to run.